# How to make use of cache data during offine in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, cache-control, okhttp

Am using retrofit 1.9 during offline i need to make use of cache response from server so how to create cache response in retrofit i have heard i can be done with okhttp but can somebody share snippet sample how to make use of cache response?

I am setting cache response like is this right way?

```
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 *1024;
    File cacheDirectory = new File(mcontext.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "HttpCache");
    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);
    OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient();
    client1.setCache(cache);
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).setClient(new OkClient(client1)).build();
    RetrofitRest retro = adapter.create(RetrofitRest.class);
```

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setCache-com.squareup.okhttp.Cache- and make sure your server uses the proper cache headers.

Comment: can u check my edited question am i doing it in right way

Comment: Sure, that should work.